# Discrete Math question involving mapping $A$ to $B$ and finding out how many functions $f:A\rightarrow B$ are there such that $f(a) = f(b) = f(c)$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $A = \{a,b,c,d\}$ and $B = \{2,3,5,7,9\}$. How many functions $f:A\rightarrow B$ are there, such that $f(a) = f(b) = f(c)?$

I'm doing some practice questions from my textbook and cannot figure out how to do this question. Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $5$ possible values that $f(a)$ can map to (2,3,5,7 and 9). Once $f(a)$ is fixed, there is only $1$ possible value of what $f(b)$ and $f(c)$ are, as they must be identical to $f(a)$. Like $f(a)$, there are 5 possible values that $f(d)$ can be. Therefore, there are $5\cdot1\cdot1\cdot5=25$ functions that satisfy the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Recall how we define a function: for every point in the domain, we choose exactly one point in the codomain. We write this choice as $x\mapsto f(x)$.

So, to determine the number of functions, you can count the number of choices for each element of the domain.

---

**Solution:** Since $|B|=5$, we have 5 choices for $f(a)$. There is now exactly one choice for $f(b)$, since by assumption, $f(a)=f(b)$. Similarly, there is one choice for $f(c)$. Finally, there are $5$ choices for $f(d)$. So in total there are $5\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 5=25$ different functions $f:A\rightarrow B$ with the property that $f(a)=f(b)=f(c)$.